# How to fold text files?

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editing

I am currently editing down multiple large text files (maybe 500 text list files) , and need to fold this files
For example this is one of my text files:

```
1966 Q3
Fort
COB
LGL
Asse
AP
BAS
Lis
46.81
11.11
9.06
4.7
4.49
2.41
1.34
```

and now i want to convert to this:

```
1966 Q3
Fort,46.81
COB,11.11
LGL,9.06
Asse,4.7
AP,4.49
BAS,2.41
Lis,1.34
```

names row always start from line 2 and continues until the first numeric line start
**I have 500 text files that this list is only one example of my files**
which script or website or regex can do this?
**Note: first line should remain unchanged**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: How do you determine where the values for the second field start? Can we assume the values for the first field start with a letter and the values for the second field start with a digit? Or do we have to count the input rows and calculating the number of output rows from this? What if the number of input lines is even? Do you have any requirements for the output file names? Do you mean you have 500 files or a few files with 500 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to do using `awk`. I know question was for Notepad++, but since the files are 1) large, 2) many, I would do it using scripting.

Awk can be downloaded for Windows and many other platforms. It works from command line.

Something like this from command line:

**Running this on multiple files**:

Example 1: a bunch of files in `d:\myfiles`:

`for %f in (d:\myfiles\*.txt) do "c:\path\to\awk.exe"  -f "c:\path\to\scriptfile.awk" "%f" > "%f_OUT.txt"`

Example 2: a single file containing a *list* of files to process:
`for /F %m in (c:\myfilelist.txt) do "c:\path\to\awk.exe" -f "c:\path\to\scriptfile.awk"  "%m" > "%m_OUT.txt"`

awk writes on the console, so output is directed to an output file. Example: d:\myfiles\xyz.txt  will be output as d:\myfiles\xyz.txt_OUT.txt.   Change as needed, or prefix a directory to use same name. Example : `> d:\converted\%~nf`. The %~n part is to get *just* the name, not a directory prefix.

To redirect all files to SAME output replace last part with `>> myoutputfile.txt`.

**Awk script file**

```
# --- 
# this assumes file format where
#   - line 1 is kept
#   - N lines that does NOT start with a number
#   - same N lines that DO start with a number
#   - output is   text,number  for each line index.
# ---
BEGIN{
   OFS=","                   # set separator to comma for output
}
# first line, just print
NR==1{
  print
}
# for line numbers over 1:
NR>1{
    if ($0 !~ /^[0-9]/ ) {   # if this does NOT start with a number...
       a[NR] = $0            # add to an array column 1
       lc++                  # increase an element counter, which starts at 0
    }
    else
    {
      b[NR-lc] = $0          # a number, add to second column
    }
}
END {
   for (i=2;i<=lc+1;i++) {   # finally print the array
     print a[i],b[i]
   }
}
```

I tested with your file:

```
1966 Q3
Fort,46.81
COB,11.11
LGL,9.06
Asse,4.7
AP,4.49
BAS,2.41
Lis,1.34
```

Comment: tnq - and now how can i run this script on a folder that contain my multiple text files? for example my folder is D:\path\folder and my awk path is C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\awk.exe

Comment: open command shell, and follow examples in answer.

Comment: ok - i tested single example and get error (was unexpected at this time.) and multiple example get this error:  
  
script.awk:16: ^ syntax error  
script.awk:21:  print a[i][0],a[i][1]  
script.awk:21: ^ syntax error  
script.awk:21:  print a[i][0],a[i][1]  
script.awk:21: ^ syntax error  
errcount: 4

Comment: Just tried. It works. `for %i in (d:\tempfiles\*.txt) do awk -f "x.awk" "%i"`   produces the correct result, which can be directed to a file.

Comment: yes - it works - i tested in https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-awk-online/ worked script but i don't know why i get error in my windows cmd

Comment: Make a temporary pastebin with your full command line and errors. Makes it simpler to see. Then give address here.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zde07pCf my cmd errors

Comment: Please try again. I think some awk versions don't have 2d array. My bad, sorry. Updated version should be OK, using a and b.

Comment: very very tnq - and my last problem is when i run script it print on console - i want to apply changes to files directly and save - what change should i do in this command? ( for %i in (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\overrrrr111111\*.txt) do awk -f "D:\script.awk" "%i" )

Comment: awk is a filter, so I would not modify in place. Make a temp dir, and output results to that, as illustrated above in example. Use redirection, like ` > "d:\tempdir\%~nf" ` . The `~n` part before variable name gives the base name, without directory.

Comment: tnq very much - this command worked for me : for %f in (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\overrrrr111111\*.txt) do "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\awk.exe"  -f "D:\script.awk" "%f" > "%f_OUT.txt" - i must learn awk language :))

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this if you just need to do this a few times where it makes sense to do it manually instead of via script or some other automation. This is, of course, assuming that the files follow the format mentioned, with half the text on lines above the other half.

Option 1. Copy and paste the first section into a spreadsheet at Column A. Then copy and paste the second section into Column B. Then copy and paste the entire thing back into notepad, and use Find+Replace to insert your commas.

Option 2. Use [column mode selection](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/editing/) to copy the first section of text and then paste it in front of the second section. After pasting, you can just press <kbd>,</kbd> to place a comma on all of the lines

Comment: Do you think this is a practicable solution for 500 files?

Comment: No, which I stated in my very first sentence. However, I read the question as being about 500 line text files, not 500x text files.

Comment: After reading your reply I'm not sure the wording in the question is unambiguous.